# How to sort array objects base on two properties

Tags: javascript

Hi i have an array of objects

```
cards = [
{ Asset: "2C.jpg",
  CardName: "2C",
  CardPlayed: 0,
  Playbell: 0,
  PlayerName: "player1",
  Rank: 2,
  Suit: "C"
},
{ Asset: "9S.jpg",
  CardName: "9S",
  CardPlayed: 0,
  Playbell: 0,
  PlayerName: "player2",
  Rank: 9,
  Suit: "S"
},
{ Asset: "6D.jpg",
  CardName: "6D",
  CardPlayed: 0,
  Playbell: 0,
  PlayerName: "player1",
  Rank: 6,
  Suit: "D"
}];
```

and i need to sort those objects base on `Suit` property but only for the object that have the `PlayerName` property value equal to `"player1"` and many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sort the array on `PlayerName` and then `Suit`:

```
cards.sort(function(x, y){
  return (
    x.PlayerName < y.PlayerName ? -1 :
    x.PlayerName > y.PlayerName ? 1 :
    x.Suit < y.Suit ? -1 :
    x.Suit > y.Suit ? 1 :
    0
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var filtered = cards.filter(function(card){
    return card.PlayerName === "player1";
});

var sorted = filtered.sort(function(a,b){
  if (a.Suit > b.Suit) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.Suit < b.Suit) {
    return -1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
});
```

According to MDN filter doesn't work on ie8 and below, you could use a polyfill  as stated on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter, or you could iterate over all items and filter them manually like this:

```
var filtered = [];
for (var i in cards){
    if (cards[i].PlayerName === "player1"){
        filtered.push(cards[i]);
    }
}

// and then sort it like before
```

Comment: Might be useful to give alternative of filter for EcmaScript < 5